# SQL - Pivot/Unpivot?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 in the format as below(simplified format) :

```
Date  Miles   Cost
```

I want to get a result like

```
        Previous Week      Current Week    Variance 
Miles        

Cost
```

How can I achieve this? Do I need pivot/unpivot or what is the easiest and performance effective way to achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't seem like you need a pivot for this at all.

Comment: How can I achieve it then? Would prefer to have a simpler SQL without multiple Unions and joins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 'Miles' AS Type, SUM(CASE WHEN date = lastweek THEN miles ELSE 0 END) as lastweek
, SUM(CASE WHEN date = thisweek THEN miles ELSE 0 END) as thisweek
SUM(CASE WHEN date = lastweek THEN miles ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN date = thisweek THEN miles ELSE 0 END) as variance
FROM yourtable
UNION
SELECT 'Cost' AS Type, SUM(CASE WHEN date = lastweek THEN cost ELSE 0 END) as lastweek
, SUM(CASE WHEN date = thisweek THEN cost ELSE 0 END) as thisweek
SUM(CASE WHEN date = lastweek THEN cost ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN date = thisweek THEN cost ELSE 0 END) as variance
FROM yourtable
```

This isn't 100% correct, but the syntax should be correct and should get you pretty close to what you're looking for

Comment: You made it look simple. I started with Joins and thought I was going to end up with ugly code. I can see it working, will work upon it. Thanks :)

Comment: I would still recommend using `UNION ALL` vs `UNION` as it's faster.